# Do we lose 7 pounds when we die?

Tags: medical-science, physics, biology, religion, spirituality

I often hear people claim that it is a fact that humans lose seven pounds when they die. Some people believe that this is 'proof' of the existence of the 'soul'. Is there any truth to this claim? I could understand a weight change after death but not a consistent one between people of different sizes.

N.B. I personally don't believe this to be true. Just thought it was a good question to ask on here.

Comment: Eventually the body will dehydrate, causing loss of mass.
But I doubt that's what the myth is about :)

Comment: If there is a loss of mass immediately post-mortem then the well-documented loss of fluid would be the simplest explanation. But seven pounds seems excessive. It might be easier to prove that someone with seven pounds of urine in his/her bladder will die soon.

Comment: 7 pounds or 7 grams? I am certain that people do not lose 7 pounds the instant they die, 7 grams would be much more difficult to measure and I would be more likely to believe that (it could happen e.g. due to evaporating more water from your skin as the properties of the tissues change.)

Comment: We want to focus our attention on doubtful claims that are widely held or are made by notable people.  Please [provide some references](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/882/what-are-the-attributes-of-a-good-question/883#883) to places where this claim is being made.

Comment: What if you have a fat soul? Do you lose like 50 pounds when you die?

Comment: @MartinScharrer - See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duncan_MacDougall_%28doctor%29

Comment: Maybe the “7 pounds” movie confused someone into thinking the amount is 7 pounds https://u.osu.edu/finney.77/seven-pounds/

Answer (score 28, accepted):

No we don't. I don't know where you got that claim from because it's not linked in the question (do link it in the question, if you can).

There is a similar myth that upon dying a body weighs 21 grams less - this is due to a (flawed) experiment performed by a Dr Duncan MacDougal. His results were never replicated and are considered to have little if no scientific merit.

More info here:

- http://www.snopes.com/religion/soulweight.asp
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soul#Weight_of_the_soul

Comment: Unfortunately it is just people I have talked to so don't have a link. It seems there is a Yahoo answers question about it but I don't feel comfortable linking to Yahoo Answers as "source".

Comment: @Oetzi: while Yahoo answers isn't a very good source to cite in an answer, I think it'd be more OK to use it in a question, if all you're trying to show is that this is actually a phenomenon that some people believe exists.